# Flutter, stream builder returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-streambuilder

I tried getting input(string) from the user using textfield, adding the input in stream, and printing the string on a different screen, but instead of the string stream builder is printing null, I understood, it's because stream doesn't have any data. But I added data in stream once the user types out something in textfield and hit save.How do I love this

Stream

```
StreamController NameStream = StreamController.broadcast();
```

Adding data to stream

```
textField()
textbuttion(
 onPressed: () {
                  addNStream() {
                    NameStream.sink.add(TextController);
                  }

                  setState(() {
                    addNStream();
                  });
```

)

Printing data in different screen

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: NameStream.stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          snapshot.data.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
        ),
      );
    },
  )
  ),
)
```

Comment: you need to setup `StreamBuilder.initialData` or check `snapshot.connectionState` / `snapshot.hasData` (see [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) official docs - they have some examples on how to do that)

Comment: I used snapshot.hasData , it printed, no data in stream

Comment: post your code then

Comment: I did, in question section

Comment: i dont see any `snapshot.hasData`

Comment: I tried this, terminal output was no data. `StreamBuilder(
        stream: addBorrowerNameStream.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("has data");
          } else {
            print("no data");
          }
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              snapshot.data.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
            ),
          );
        },
      )`

Comment: because you use `snapshot.data.toString()` even if `snapshot.hasData` is set to `false`

Comment: Could please explain more..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243343/discussion-between-ganesh-sivakumar-and-pskink).

Comment: you return `Text(snapshot.data.toString()` in both cases - if `snapshot.hasData` is true and false

Comment: That statement was just to check if stream has data. Just want to print string in screen but it printed null. So, used that condition statement.

Comment: it printed null because `snapshot.hasData` is false - it means there is no data: data is null, `hasData` official documentation says: *"Returns whether this snapshot contains a non-null data value.

This can be false even when the asynchronous computation has completed successfully, if the computation did not return a non-null value. For example, a Future<void> will complete with the null value even if it completes successfully."*

Comment: True, but I have added data(textController) into the stream right? why streamBuilder doesn't display that text.

Comment: `class StreamBuilderTest extends StatelessWidget {
final ctrl = StreamController<String>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
stream: ctrl.stream,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
return Center(
child: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () => ctrl.add(DateTime.now().toString()),
child: Text('press me, ${snapshot.data}'),
),
);
}
);
}
}`

Comment: I still couldn't understand why it returns null, could you explain.

Comment: bacause you are using `snapshot.data` when you cannot do that - you can ONLY use `snapshot.data` when `snapshot.hasData` is set to `true`

Comment: Yeah, but why snapshot doesn't have any data, I've added data in stream. So, snapshot should data right?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a broadcast stream.  Items added to a broadcast stream when nothing is listening are silently discarded.

Comment: Could you please explain it with code

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `broadcast()` your `StreamBuilder` don't listen to the data in the `NameStream.stream` in the initialization.

because the `NameStream.stream` doesn't have any listeners so `StreamBuilder` assume that the is no data so he doesn't check, this is the reason for the null.

to solve the problem you need to add listener (`initSatate`) before you add the event to the stream this will allow `StreamBuilder` to recognize that there is data in the stream.